# NodeNotFoundError in Django

Tags: python, django, command-line

Every time I try to run the server or migrate I get this error in the command line:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration  auth.0009_user_following dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'account', u'0002_contact')
```

I did make a following system but i can't find were it is. I also tried deleting my some of my django projects but I still get this error. Please help me.

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations appname` first?

Comment: if you use same django with two project,you may get this error,the reason is your project one has makemigration,so you project two can't extend your first project's migrations.solution is use virtualenv.

Comment: no but i will try now

Comment: what do you mean can you explain

Comment: what do you mean by using the same django

Comment: you have to use virtualenv for works with differents projects, Django is a folder with code, your project is sniping this folder and your another project too, so you need different Django folder for each one. I don't know if you understand this, let me know

Comment: anyway show migrations folder

Comment: I do understand, thanks